# JavaScript code will not output geojson data onto leaflet map

Tags: javascript, dc.leaflet.js

I am trying to output geojson data onto a leaflet.js map but the console output in browser outputs the following line: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'features' of null"

The geojson has roughly 300,000 latitude and longitude points. I did cut the geojson down to 95 points and I was able to plot those on the map. When I try the larger geojson file though, it will not plot.

Here is the js code:

```
var myMap = L.map("map", {
  center: [-10.01194, -51.11583],
  zoom: 5
});


// Adding tile layer

L.tileLayer("https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}", {
  attribution: "Map data &copy; <a href='https://www.openstreetmap.org/'>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href='https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/'>CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href='https://www.mapbox.com/'>Mapbox</a>",
  maxZoom: 20,
  id: "mapbox.streets",
  accessToken: API_KEY
}).addTo(myMap);

var newtry = "brazilian_fires2008.txt";

// Grab the data with d3

d3.json(newtry, function(response) {

  // Create a new marker cluster group

  var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

  // Loop through data

  var lon;
  var lat;

  for(var a = 0; a < 10; a++)
  {
     lon = response.features[a].geometry.coordinates[1];
     lat = response.features[a].geometry.coordinates[0];

     markers.addLayer(L.marker([lon, lat]));
  }
        // Add our marker cluster layer to the map
    myMap.addLayer(markers);
  });
```

And here is the first portion of the geojson:

```
var dataset = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "acq_date": "2008-01-01",
        "latitude": -9.2096,
        "longitude": -36.8779,
        "brightness": 360.2,
        "confidence": 100,
        "bright_t31": 314.7,
        "frp": 92.0
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -36.8779,
          -9.2096
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "acq_date": "2008-01-01",
        "latitude": -6.0089999999999995,
        "longitude": -38.3049,
        "brightness": 362.1,
        "confidence": 100,
        "bright_t31": 313.4,
        "frp": 109.5
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -38.3049,
          -6.0089999999999995
        ]
      }
    },
```

The console output in browser outputs the following line:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'features' of null

I believe the js code is not able to read the geojson. I am expecting there to be several thousand points but I am getting nothing.

Comment: According to the browser console,the error is being flagged on line 29 of the js code which is:

 lon = response.features[a].geometry.coordinates[1];
 lat = response.features[a].geometry.coordinates[0];

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'features' of null`: This probably means that `response` is null, and it fails trying to evaluate `response.features`. Although it's possible that something like this is happening in the 3rd-party library rather than in your code (but still probably caused by bad data you're sending to the library). Can you get a full stacktrace? You might be able to get it by clicking something on the log line.

Comment: As for the file `brazilian_fires2008.txt`: What happens if you only include the first 100,000? Or from 50,000 to 100,000? Try out different parts of the file to narrow down where the bad part is.

Comment: trying at different quantities did not work.

Comment: You said it worked with the first 95 points. Does it work with the first 200? 500? 1000?

Comment: it does not work for those quntities

Comment: Are you saying it works with the first 95 but not with the first 96? What happens if you just send the 96th one? What is number 96? Do you see anything weird about it?

Answer (score 0):

If your error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'features' of null",
then dataset it not properly stored in the file 'brazilian_fires2008.txt'.
Please check the filename or filepath again and make sure it points to the right path of the file.

Your current code still has an error : 'Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined'
You a is iterated until 10. So change it into  response.features.length;

```
var dataset = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "acq_date": "2008-01-01",
        "latitude": -9.2096,
        "longitude": -36.8779,
        "brightness": 360.2,
        "confidence": 100,
        "bright_t31": 314.7,
        "frp": 92.0
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -36.8779,
          -9.2096
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "acq_date": "2008-01-01",
        "latitude": -6.0089999999999995,
        "longitude": -38.3049,
        "brightness": 362.1,
        "confidence": 100,
        "bright_t31": 313.4,
        "frp": 109.5
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -38.3049,
          -6.0089999999999995
        ]
      }
    },
 ]
};

var myMap = L.map("map", {
  center: [-10.01194, -51.11583],
  zoom: 5
});


// Adding tile layer

L.tileLayer("https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}", {
  attribution: "Map data &copy; <a href='https://www.openstreetmap.org/'>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href='https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/'>CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href='https://www.mapbox.com/'>Mapbox</a>",
  maxZoom: 20,
  id: "mapbox.streets",
  accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic21hcnRuZWd1cnkiLCJhIjoiY2p5aGFjdTVzMDI2NzNjbDdyYjhjZDdmeSJ9.Zl1LGRGQsFAxUP_jBqkZBQ'
}).addTo(myMap);

var response = dataset;

// Grab the data with d3


  // Create a new marker cluster group

  var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

  // Loop through data

  var lon;
  var lat;

  for(var a = 0; a < response.features.length; a++)
  {
     lon = response.features[a].geometry.coordinates[1];
     lat = response.features[a].geometry.coordinates[0];

     markers.addLayer(L.marker([lon, lat]));
  }
        // Add our marker cluster layer to the map
    myMap.addLayer(markers);
    
<html>

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
<!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js"
   ></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" style="height:180px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how do I know if the file is not stored correctly? I have tried using all file paths of the file...